# SSIS configuration connection manager throwing error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

*The connection "xxx.dtsx" is not found.This error is thrown by connections collection when the specific connection element is not found*

SSIS package is configured through SQL server SSIS configuration table.Its working fine in local machine when I tried to push the package to another machine its showing the above error

Comment: Are you using SSIS Catalog, SSISDB database, and Project level deployment?

Comment: File deployment I mean package level deployment